# Name of a particular condition on sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've come across a certain condition on a sequence that I figure I'm probably not the first to come across, but I can't work out what it's called.

If the sequence has two elements $(a,b)$, then the condition would only imply:

- $a>b$

If the sequence has three elements $(a,b,c)$, then the condition would imply:

- $a>b>c$
- $(a-b)>(b-c)$

If the sequence has four elements $(a,b,c,d)$, then the condition would imply:

- $a>b>c>d$
- $(a-b)>(b-c)>(c-d)$
- $(a-b)-(b-c)>(b-c)-(c-d)$

If the sequence has five elements $(a,b,c,d,e)$, then the condition would imply:

- $a > b > c > d >e$
- $(a-b) > (b-c) > (c-d) > (d-e)$
- $(a-b)-(b-c) > (b-c)-(c-d) > (c-d)-(d-e)$
- $((a-b)-(b-c))-((b-c)-(c-d)) > ((b-c)-(c-d))-((c-d)-(d-e))$

$\ldots$

Can anybody think of how I can compactly define this condition? Is this condition defined/named anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is saying that the [forward differences](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ForwardDifference.html) of odd (resp., even) order are strictly negative (resp. strictly positive).

If you had instead

- $a > b > c$
- $(b-a) > (c-b)$

etc., then it would say that the forward differences (of all orders) are strictly negative.